# The English for "à l’assurance de mes sentiments distingués"

Tags: expressions

I’m reading a motivation letter that’s quite formal, especially the last line.

> Monsieur, en réponse à votre annonce parue hier, j’ai l’honneur de
>   poser ma candidature au poste d’informaticien.
>
> … Je vous prie de bien vouloir trouver ci-joint mon CV, qui vous
>   fournira de plus amples renseignements sur mon parcours professionnel.
>
> Dans l’espoir que vous voudrez bien considérer favorablement ma
>   candidature, je vous prie de croire, monsieur, à l’assurance de mes
>   sentiments distingués.

Normally i just put something as “yours faithfully” But is there a way to translate the last paragraph to English as formal as it is in French?

Comment: You should probably ask this on an English SE site...

Comment: @LaurentS. I did consider this, then I have a second thought that probably more French speaking people could speak English than English speaking ppl can speak French...

Comment: Certainly, and there's a fair chance you might get an answer, but still this isn't the goal of this site. You might simply google for a formal ending in English, or ask it on another SE site rather than looking for a translation of something which is not easily translatable...

Comment: @LaurentS. There’s no French-English translation forum on SE ..

Comment: @athos Proportionnally, that is probably true, but absolutely it might be wrong!

Comment: What about https://english.stackexchange.com/ ; if they don't do translations they might still be able to say whether an English equivalent can be found, who knows, even communicate that equivalent to you.

Comment: No, there isn't such a SE site, but SE hasn't to answer each and every question in the world... so better turn your question differently to fit English.SE for example. If somebody wanted to get the same translation in Japanese or Russian, it would become very obvious that French.SE isn't the place to go...

Comment: I tend to be on the side of @athos on this one. I think this should be the right place for this kind of questions for the same reason that I'm writing in english right now whereas this is not a French-English Language forum but French Language forum. You don't see here people asking questions in Spanish...

Comment: I must disagree: https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Asking for a translation is already "prohibited" here, even when the translation is to French language, so I'm quite sure asking for a translation to English language is even more misplaced. There are 2 SE sites where you can specifically ask about how to say something in English, [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and [English language learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) where this question would be more suited, and probably get more and better answers as long as it is not asked starting from a French sentence.

Comment: This is off-topic as inquiring about a possible phrasing in English isn't in the scope of French language

Comment: I’m just a bit amused that, put aside this forum’s rules discouraging translation topic, French-English translation seems to some one not suitable to here, and of course French-Japanese or French-Russian neither, so ... French does not need translation? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in trying to transcribe this piece of French language is that it might not be customary at all and  so puzzle your correspondent or cause a misinterpretation of your intent. In any case I don't believe that you can "go all the way" in English; it seems to me it would be too strange.

Although the particular combination I suggest here is very probably not used at all in the place you intend for it, its terms can be found in other parts of a letter; the only inconvenient is the transgression of customs, accepted ways, and on the ground of the adage "when in doubt leave it out" I wouldn't use that type of ending without the assurance of causing myself no wrong (specially in a letter of application for a job).

> Hoping my application will be considered favourably, I extend to you my best regards.
>
> Truly yours,